Find Missing Files not working right?
As you would guess from the image, I'm trying to use the Find Missing Files option for textures on a model I grabbed online, but this keeps happening.
I tried this with one model, it didn't work so I figured it was a problem with that specific model. But now Its apparent that its a pattern, I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this.


Have you only tried in Blender to find the files or have you made sure they are actually there in the directory stated in the message and the files have the names given there? And when using Find Missing Files files, how have you done it? Just clicked the button or navigated to a directory where the files actually are?

I have only tried looking in Blender by clicking on the texture folder and going from there. And when using Find Missing Files, I did click the button and hoped that would do it. Did I do something wrong?

The Find Missing Files function is not a general search function like in Windows Explorer. It is there to make new connections if images are linked to a path which does not exist anymore. Let's say there are dozens of images with a path C:\textures\ but now the path is C:\pictures. Instead of opening each image separately from the new folder, with Find Missing Files you can go into the new folder and then after clicking the button Blender looks there for all image filenames which are missing and redirects the links for all images it finds there and in subfolders.

So I just need to rename the files?

Where did I say you should rename the files? Do the files Blender is missing exist somewhere in a folder or not? If so, choose Find Missing Files, navigate to the folder where they are and click the button. If they do not exist, what do you expect Blender to find or which files do you want to rename?

Thats the issue, Im clicking the exact file folder that came with the model with the textures needed and I get the same result every single time.

I have to ask again: have you checked in any other software like Windows Explorer if the files are actually there??? Could you show a screen of the path and folder the message refers to and show the files are? And show a screenshot of Find Missing Files browser before clicking the button?

Same thing happened to me today, it was weird. It might be a tiny Blender 4.2 bug, but when I dragged one of the missing videos into the VSE (after a failed attempt at finding the missing files), everything worked nicely all of a sudden and Blender had no problem playing the files.

It's possible you need to give Blender somewhere to look for the missing files. I have recently had some success with creating a directory for the downloaded file and then unpacking the asset files to the directory where the Blender file is, choosing Create When Necessary.
If the asset files are packed into the Blender file, you'll force a download of them into a place where your various file and asset managers, in your operating system and in Blender, can find them. Then you can repack the files as you like.

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.
